# Unset variable value assigned within if statement inside a nested for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to make one batch file to read parameters from the file and pass it to `ant` for deployment.

I have made the below batch file:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo on

IF EXIST "D:\testfile1.txt" (
    echo Do one thing

    set string=
    set /p string=< D:\testfile1.txt
    echo value taken from file is %string

    for /f "tokens=2,4,6 delims==:" %%G IN ("%string%") DO (

        echo %%G %%H %%I
        set env=%%G
        set dom=%%H
        set com=%%I
        echo ENV !env!
        echo DOM !dom!
        echo COM !com!


        cd D:\kpn_eai\EAI_FIXED\branches\kpn_eai_fixed\fixed\build\scripts

        %ANT_HOME%\bin\xanteai deploy %%G %%H %%I

    )
) ELSE (
    echo Do another thing
)

endlocal
```

In `testfile1.txt` I have parameters in below format:

```
Environment=Env_Name1:Domain=Domain_Name1:Component=Component_name1
```

Parameters are different deployments. When I am running the above code it is giving below output

```
D:\>echo off
Do one thing Ant home is C:\tibco\ant\apache-ant-1.9.13
value taken from file is Environment=Env_name1:Domain=Domain_Name1:Component=Component_name1
Env_name1 Domain_Name1 Component_name1
ENV Env_name1
DOM Domain_Name1
COM Component_name1
```

Deployments starts after this.

The issue I am facing is when I run this code for different parameters *(in `testfile1.txt`)* the values of `ENV`, `DOM` and `COM` remains same regardless of any parameters read from `testfile1.txt`.

Can anyone help me to correct this code and let me know how can I just assign the values read from file to a variable and pass it to `ant` for deployment?

NOTE:- This batch file will be placed in scheduler which will check for `testfile1.txt` after every 5 minutes, when it finds that file deployment process gets triggered. Thus I have included if condition to check availability of file.

Comment: Why do you think only `env/dom/com` need the exclamation marks inside a code block? This applies also to the var `!string!` Simply reverse your if logic `If not exist` and exit the batch file then, so no code block is neccessary.

Comment: @LotPings I wouldn't say that reversing the condition is a good advise without knowing a context. OP could want to do "another thing" instead of exit.

Comment: Your provided output is not the result of the batch file you've posted!

Comment: @montonero Well, 1st choice is to properly use delayedexpansion. 2nd you are right, I just wanted to circumvent a `goto` if possible, but that's up to OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first split the read line at the colons with a simple for and
obtain the variable names `env,dom,com` from the content.

Here preceeded with an underscore for easier output.

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\03\08\SO_55061545_.cmd
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "FileIn=D:\testfile1.txt"

IF not EXIST "%FileIn%" (
    echo Do another thing
    Goto :somewhere
)

echo Do one thing
set "string="
set /p "string="<"%FileIn%"
echo value taken from file is %string%

for %%A in ("%string::=" "%") do for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%B IN ("%%~A") DO (
    echo %%A %%B %%C
    set var=%%B
    set "_!var:~0,3!=%%C"
)
set _

:: cd D:\kpn_eai\EAI_FIXED\branches\kpn_eai_fixed\fixed\build\scripts
:: %ANT_HOME%\bin\xanteai deploy %_env% %_dom% %_com%

endlocal

:somewhere
```

---

```
>  SO_55061545_.cmd
Do one thing
value taken from file is Environment=Env_Name1:Domain=Domain_Name1:Component=Component_name1
"Environment=Env_Name1" Environment Env_Name1
"Domain=Domain_Name1" Domain Domain_Name1
"Component=Component_name1" Component Component_name1
_Com=Component_name1
_Dom=Domain_Name1
_Env=Env_Name1
```

Comment: Idea of reversing the if statement actually worked for me... And yes i am new to batch coding that's the reason i was not sure how to use SET enabledelayedexpansion properly. By the way thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: @LotPings I don't quite get why you need a `goto`, `else` is fine and much cleaner. Code blocks do code more readable.

Comment: @montonero If properly used yes.  I tend to put the shorter to handle condition first, so program flow is more clear and excessive nesting of code blocks can be avoided. But that is just my personal preference. You surely know that delayedexpansion is **THE** most often occuriong issue.

Comment: @LotPings For sure the delayed expansion isn't a most well known feature in batch scripts.

Answer (score 1):

There really shouldn't be any need to be `set`ting or `echo`ing everything as you go, so why not just do something like this instead:

```bat
@Echo Off
If Exist "testfile1.txt" (Set /P "string="<"testfile1.txt"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo value taken from file is !string!
    For /F "Tokens=2,4,6 Delims==:" %%A In ("!string!") Do (
        CD /D "D:\kpn_eai\EAI_FIXED\branches\kpn_eai_fixed\fixed\build\scripts"
        "%ANT_HOME%\bin\xanteai" deploy %%A %%B %%C)
    EndLocal) Else Echo Do another thing
```

Comment: setting EnableDelayedExpansion inside if statement will only have its scope inside if block only right?

Comment: in my code after removing all the echoes which I used as marker to keep a track of values, my code looks the same inspite I didn't set EnableDelayedExpansion inside if statement

Comment: Yes, because I read your requirment as 'how to assign the values to pass to `ant`'. Once they've been passed, you don't need them any more, so the `EndLocal` removes them from the environment. Oh and BTW, you code was almost the same, except that you needed to learn to use doublequotes properly and also ensure that you use the `/D` option with the `CD` command. The main issue as you've already eluded to was that you needed to enable delayed expansion at the right time, which is what I've demonstrated above.